# How to submit a model form with factory values by capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have a Client model that requires following fields:

`validates :name, :address1, :city, :state, :country, :zipcode,

                    :contactname, :email, presence: true`

Now I'm writting tests for creating a new client. I create a client object with FactoryGirl, how do I fill the form with factory values without manually writing `fill_in "field_id", with: factory.field_value` for every field, like I'm already doing, as shown in below code.

```
describe "with valid information" do
  let(:client) { FactoryGirl.create(:client) }

  before(:each) do
    visit new_client_path
    fill_in "client_name", with: client.name
    fill_in "client_address1", with: client.address1
    fill_in "client_city", with: client.city
    fill_in "client_state", with: client.state
    select client.country, from: "client_country"
    fill_in "client_zipcode", with: client.zipcode
    fill_in "client_contactname", with: client.contactname
    fill_in "client_email", with: client.email
  end

  it "should create a client" do
    expect { click_button "Create Client" }.to change(Client, :count)
  end

  describe "success messages" do
    before { click_button "Create Client" }
    it { should have_content('created') }
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't FactoryGirl already save it to the database?

Comment: Yes it should. In order to just generate attributes one should use  `FactoryGirl.build(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The only way to shorten it I see is iterating though an array:

```
%w(name address1 city state zipcode contactname email).each do |field|
  fill_in "client_#{field}", with: client.send(field.to_sym)
end
```

But this will work only in very simple case, for the fields of one type (as you see, I skipped `client_country`).

So, there is no general solution of the task how to map model attributes to form fields, because form fields may be of different types, and mapping may be more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with `fill_in` for each field, for sake of clarity :)